# Errors for OpenCV in Visual Studio 12 in windows 8.1. Here's the simple code when debugging it says some errors. How can i fix this?

Tags: c++, windows, image, opencv, image-processing

```
    {**#include <opencv\cv.h>
    #include <opencv\highgui.h>sing namespace cv;
    int main()
    {
        // Create matrix to store.
        Mat image;
        // initializing capture
        VideoCapture cap;
        cap.open(0);
        //create window to show image
        namedWindow("window",1);
        // copy webcam stream to image
        cap>>image;
        //print image to screen
        imshow("window",image);

        // delay 33ms
        waitKey(33);

    }**
```

> ```
> and the errors are 
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> **'And, its errors are  ''OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Uzzal
>     Das\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\OpenCV\Debug\OpenCV.exe'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Opencv243\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_core243d.dll'. Cannot find
>     or open the PDB file. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Opencv243\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_highgui243d.dll'. Cannot
>     find or open the PDB file. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Uzzal Das\Documents\Visual
>     Studio 2012\Projects\OpenCV\Debug\msvcp100d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Uzzal Das\Documents\Visual
>     Studio 2012\Projects\OpenCV\Debug\msvcr100d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols
>     loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\PROGRA~2\SupTab\SearchProtect32.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>     PDB file. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devenum.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdmo.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qcap.dll'. Symbols
>     loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\quartz.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksproxy.ax'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksuser.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vidcap.ax'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Kswdmcap.ax'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc42.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. The thread 0x17a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>     'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qedit.dll'.
>     Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>     (Win32): Loaded
>     'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17056_none_dadc5d1c5bc8ab48\GdiPlus.dll'.
> ```
>
> Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>           (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>           'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'.
>           Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdim32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>           file. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdusc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>           file. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dim700.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>           (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdusc32.dll' 'OpenCV.exe'
>           (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdim32.dll' 'OpenCV.exe'
>           (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdim32.dll'. Cannot find or
>           open the PDB file. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdusc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>           file. 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Unloaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdusc32.dll' 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Unloaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdim32.dll' 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'OpenCV.exe'
>           (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\PROGRA~2\SupTab\SearchProtect32.dll' The
>           thread 0x15ec has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x4c0 has
>           exited with code 0 (0x0). 'OpenCV.exe' (Win32): Unloaded
>           'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msyuv.dll' The thread 0x14d4 has exited with
>           code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x9f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The
>           thread 0x15f4 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '[6988]
>           OpenCV.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).'
>
> ```
>     ----------
> '**
> ```

Comment: None of those are errors. You can install symbols if you really want to step into microsoft code but its not necessary. Although you are using compiled opencv for the wrong compiler. The vc10 binaries are for Visual Studio 2010 not 2012. You should use vc11 binaries for Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The can not load pbd files problem for opencv is caused by using dlls compiled with a different compiler than you are using. In this case you are using Visual Studio 2010 dlls in your Visual Studio 2012 application. In general is not safe to mix compilers by using dlls compiled with a different version of Visual Studio or mixing debug and release in the same application. The main reason is when you do this you will have more than 1 independent heap. You can not safely allocate memory in 1 heap and free it in a second heap. This will cause heap corruption which can cause a random looking crash because the corruption may not crash on the first allocation / deallocation after the heap becomes corrupt.

To fix this make sure you setup your project to use the correct opencv dlls for your compiler. For Visual Studio 2012 the correct dlls will be in the vc11 folder.